# How to write reusable functions for columns in by group operations in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

There are some columns(~20) I need in many data.tables, how do I encapsulate the operations in a function?

For example, I want to have column `a1` and `a2` in every data.table, the fastest method is to copy and paste codes:

```
n= 10
m = 2
d = data.table( p = c(1:n)*1.0, q = 1:m)
dnew = d[, list(a1 = mean(p),a2 = max(p), b = 2) , by = q] #copy and paste
```

I want write reusable functions like this,

```
f <- function(d) with(d, list( a1 = mean(p), a2 = max(p))) #return list
dnew = d[, c(f(.SD), list( b = 2)) , by = q]
```

or this,

```
g <- function(d)d[, list(a1 = mean(p), a2 = max(p)), by = q] #return data.table
dnew1 = g(d)
dnew2 = d[, list(b = 2),by = q]
dnew = merge(dnew1, dnew2, by = "q")
```

However, both are very slow when number of groups(m) is very large.

Comment: Writing a function that depends on it's argument having a `$p` element does not seem terribly robust. Why put this in a function at all? Generally, I don't think you'll find that you can have both speed and idiosyncratic functions. Data.table optimizes particularly for `max` by groups, for example, and won't be able to do that if the task is obfuscated.

Comment: Your `f` function example is about as fast as your "copy and paste" example. I think your bottleneck is somewhere else. Can you provide more detail about how you're calling `f` at the higher level?

Comment: @Frank Modifying copy and paste codes in 10 different locations makes me feel horrible when I think about DRY principle.

Comment: @Artem You can try to modify `n` and `m` in the above codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can follow [the metaprogramming help from FAQ 1.6](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#ok-but-i-dont-know-the-expressions-in-advance.-how-do-i-programatically-pass-them-in):

```
# expression instead of a function
fe = quote(list(a1 = mean(p), a2 = max(p)))

# add another element
e = fe
e$b = 2

# eval following FAQ
d[, eval(e), by=q]
```

I borrowed the `e$b = 2` syntax from [Hadley Wickham's notes on expressions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#calls).

This does work, but looking at `d[, eval(e), by=q, verbose=TRUE]` we see that `max` is not getting optimized. Since `b` is just a constant, I'd add it in a second step:

```
extrae = quote(`:=`(b = 2))
d[, eval(fe), by=q][, eval(extrae)][]

# or if working interactively...
d[, eval(fe), by=q][, b := 2][]
```

With `verbose=TRUE`, we'll now see that `fe` is optimized to `list(gmean(p), gmax(p))`.